# How to execute WPF assembly from memory?

Tags: c#, wpf, reflection, assemblies

If the `ms` variable is a `MemoryStream` and contains a .Net assembly, you would normally run it like this:

```
var asm   = Assembly.Load(ms.ToArray());
var entry = asm.EntryPoint;
var inst  = asm.CreateInstance(entry.Name);
entry.Invoke(inst, null);
```

This works well on console applications and windows forms applications, however, WPF applications throw an exception:

```
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

With the inner exception of type `System.IO.IOException`:

```
Cannot locate resource 'mainwindow.xaml'.
```

The stacktrace is really big, but guessing from the start, it can't locate the resources when loaded from memory:

```
at MS.Internal.AppModel.ResourcePart.GetStreamCore(FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
at System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.GetStream(FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
at System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.GetStream()
at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Uri resourceLocator, Boolean bSkipJournaledProperties)
at System.Windows.Application.DoStartup()
at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1(Object unused)
[...]
```

How could I fix this?

Comment: If due to Microsoft's implementation it requires a file to load the resources, would a temporary exe file work, that only has the resources? If so, how can I create one on-the-fly and link the assembly in the MemoryStream to it?

Answer (score 0):

When you load an assembly dynamically from a MemoryStream, its working directory will be that of your own assembly. That directory is unlikely to contain the XAML markup files referred to by the assembly.

Try setting your Environment.CurrentDirectory to a new directory containing the necessary XAML, at least for the duration of the assembly loading and class instantiation.

Comment: I tried this, but the problem still persists. However, I expected it not to work, since the resources are in the assembly in the MemoryStream and not in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by SAKryukov on codeproject [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/189644/Executing-WPF-Assembly-from-Memory.aspx?cmt=94182#answer1), I made the WPF app into a library with a custom entry point which I then invoke with my 2nd application. The problem seems to lie with the way that App.xaml implements the starturi